# css() doesn't finish before next statement in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, timing

I have this piece of code:

```
$(this).css('color', 'red');
if(confirm('Do you want to delete this item?'))
    window.location.href = link;
else
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
```

But unfortunately the css('color', red) doesn't execute before the confirm() is called. If i use animate instead of css, and perform the confirm() in the callback function it get's executed **before** the animation is actually complete.

Note this issue doesn't appear in chrome, there it works fine (for me).

Answer (score 1):

The confirm dialog may prevent the page from being updated until it's closed. To avoid this, give the browser time to do things before opening it:

```
var $this = $(this); // in the callback we cannot use `this`
$this.css('color', 'red');
window.setTimeout(function() {
    if(confirm('Do you want to delete this item?'))
        window.location.href = link;
    else
        $this.css('color', 'black');
}, 0);
```

Comment: Similar to VisioN's answer, this works sometimes, sometimes it doesn't - for me.

Comment: Have you considered using a html-based confirm dialog instead of the native one? This would not have those drawbacks.

Comment: Yup, it's a good idea, just this problem intrigued me, so i wanted to try to find a solution, before i'd develop some workaround ;)

Answer (score 0):

Small timeout should help:

```
var el = $(this);
el.css('color', 'red');
setTimeout(function() {
    if(confirm('Do you want to delete this item?'))
        window.location.href = link;
    else
        el.css('color', 'black');
}, 1);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jWRDq/

Comment: Seems to work in the jsfiddle, but on my page it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. An interval of 10 will do the trick, but i guess than it is kind of dependent on every visitors computer?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you in an if statement:

Agreed with tester - firebug was too lenient.

```
var $this = false;
if($this = $(this).css('color', 'red')) {
 if(confirm('Do you want to delete this item?')) {
  window.location.href = link;
 } else {
  $this.css('color', 'black');
 }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to edit it? What did I miss? -- it should evaluate to true (it's not a comparison).

Comment: You miss to remove `var` from the `if` statement and define `$this` before.

Comment: Defining var in the statement makes it available only if the right hand side of the operation finishes.  This syntax is valid and doesn't cause an error.  Also, it requires the result to be assigned to a variable, so it requires the css to be finished before it returns, which then creates a break in execution before confirm() is called - in theory.  I can't replicate the original bug on safari.

Comment: You can try your previous version, it will raise something like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`.

Comment: Ah =) depends on what mode I do firebug in - note to testers - editing answer. Thanks!

Comment: Well, this works in a way: if i ask for the color in the confirm it gives me rgb(255, 0, 0), unfortunately the browser doesn't seem to draw that quickly enough, resulting in no color change. (just goes back to black)

Comment: Stupid question: is there any other code executing elsewhere that adjusts the colour or have you got a jsfiddle that shows this behaviour in the right context for others to tweak to try to fix it to behave correctly?